# image gallery prev and next buttons not working

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Hi I have a simple thumbnail gallery of two rows of 5 images for a total of ten and my previous and next buttons aren't working and I can not figure out why they are not working? 
I would like when you click on previous or next button it moves the gallery section accordingly. Here is a link to what I have : http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/YRTzG/21/[question]
any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you failed to include jquery, so `$` is not defined.

Comment: Beau thanks for the response. I actually do have the jquery library file included on my original file. I have selected the jquery library from the side menu in my fiddle and still not working. Please advise and thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forget to include jquery library file. 
Include the following line in your code...

```
<script type="text/javascript"      
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Shivaji - I actually do have the jquery library file included on my original file. I have selected the jquery library from the side menu in my fiddle and still not working. Please advise and thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at image ,at top left side black selected rectangle which showing that you are forgot to add JQuery library file

[image]

Comment: Hi Shivaji... Thanks again for your response. Here is my updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/YRTzG/21/   appreciate any help you can give! Thank you!